# When adding pills with horizontal orientation, div height doesn't increase correctly

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I'm working on a web application, and I have a datatable where you can filter via an API call. Upon adding filters, Material Design chips get added in horizontal orientation. When I add too much chips, my text in my div goes over the text above it.

This is my code:

```
<!-- ABOVE IS ANOTHER MAT TOOLBAR ROW WITH 3 INPUTS AS SHOWN IN THE PICTURE BELOW -->
   <mat-toolbar-row class="controls">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <span>Filtering {{getTotalDataSize()}}
            <span *ngIf="type === 'user'" i18n>users</span>
            <span *ngIf="type === 'role'" i18n>roles</span>
            <span *ngIf="type === 'entitlement'" i18n>entitlements</span>
            <span *ngIf="type === 'application'" i18n>applications</span>:</span>
          <span *ngIf="clusterConditions.length == 0">&nbsp;no filters applied</span>
          <div *ngIf="clusterConditions.length > 0 || isInGroupByMode()">
            <mat-chip-list>
              <mat-chip *ngFor="let condition of clusterConditions" [selectable]="false" [removable]="true" (removed)="removeCondition(condition)">
                <span *ngIf="condition.attr.name">{{condition.attr.name | capitalize}} {{condition.match}} "{{condition.val}}"</span>
                <span *ngIf="!condition.attr.name">Contains "{{condition.val}}"</span>
                <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip>
              <mat-chip *ngIf="isInGroupByMode()" [selectable]="false" [removable]="true" (removed)="changeGroupByMode(false)">
                <span>Grouped by {{groupByAttribute.name}}</span>
                <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
              </mat-chip>
            </mat-chip-list>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="getDataSize()" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10"></mat-paginator>
        </div>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
```

I tried fiddling with some `display: block/flex;` and `box-sizing: border-box;`, but I can't seem to figure it out!

An example of what it looks like when adding too much chips:

[image]

I'd like the 'Filtering ...' to show beneath the input fields!

EDIT: Wanted behaviour:

[image]

Note: The row has two columns, the chips column and the navigator on the right. When there are to much pills, a next row has to start as shown in the picture above, in the column div of the pills, not of the paginator.
Either the pills start next to the 'Filtering ... :' or beneath it (doesn't really matter)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include your CSS please?

Comment: @JamieButtonsCoulter I haven't made any custom css yet, next to a few padding/font changes. I solely use Material Design. The last picture shows 2 MatToolbarRows, and in the last one (with the pills), I have two div columns using Bootstrap. The first div, that contains the pills, has a span and another div containing the list of pills. That's it, no more css used. For some reason after inspecting the elements, the MatToolbarRow height doesn't change, whilst the height of the div column (col-md-9) increases!